# How do I make Visio header rows behave like Excel header rows?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

A few times when I was working in Excel with documents that had large amounts of data, as you scroll down, the header (first cell in the column) stayed visible. I don't remember telling it to do this, but it's behavior I want.

How do I get this same behavior in Visio 2010?

I'm making a timeline, and the header is just a bunch of text boxes on the left-hand side. I want to make it stay visible as I scroll down the timeline to update things.

Is this even possible?

Comment: For reference the Excel feature you are talking about is "Freeze Panes" (there are two others, "Freeze Top Row" and "Freeze First Column" which do exactly what they say) and is under the View tab in the Ribbon (Excel 2007/2010)

Comment: I would +1, but I don't have enough community points to do so... But +1 for shufler

Answer (score 2):

workaround: create two windows into the same visio diagram, stack them on top of each other, ensure zoom is the same on both windows so that the columns line up, and when you scroll in the bottom window, the top window stays put.  Disabling the ribbon in the bottom window helps the diagram appear more continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I've not been able to find a way for objects in Visio to be 'frozen' like so the don't move as the page scrolls around (as per the Freeze Panes / Rows feature of Excel). I've been trying to do the same thing with Visio Swim Lane charts where I want the lane names to always be shown.

Comment: But I found this workaround. http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=3341.0

Comment: Could you edit that link into your answer with a short summary of the information it contains?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all and paste in a an excel sheet. Freeze first column or top row based on directions of swimlanes. Align row or column width height accordingly to the title of swimlanes. It embeds the document and you are able to scroll accordingly.